# Disable notebook monitor and set custom resolution to external monitor in Xorg

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, multi-monitor, resolution

I am trying to create a script which is disabling the laptop's monitor and set the resolution of my external monitor to 3440x1440 @ 44fps. I am using 44fps because this is the maximum refresh rate my video card supports. This is the output of xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.02 +  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 819mm x 346mm
   3840x2160     30.00    30.00    25.00    25.00    24.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I am setting the resolution of my external monitro with the following three commands:

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_44.00"  299.75  3440 3664 4024 4608  1440 1443 1453 1479 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 "3440x1440_44.00"
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode "3440x1440_44.00"
```

And I also have tried to create a bash script in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/45-custom_xrandr_settings`:

```
EXTERNAL_OUTPUT="HDMI-1-1"
INTERNAL_OUTPUT="eDP-1-1"

xrandr |grep $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT | grep " connected "
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --off
    xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_44.00"  299.75  3440 3664 4024 4608  1440 1443 1453 1479 -hsync +vsync
    xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 "3440x1440_44.00"
    xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode "3440x1440_44.00"
else
    xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto --output $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT --off
fi
```

I have also tried to create `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.cfg` file with the following content:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1-1"
    Modeline "3440x1440_44.00"  299.75  3440 3664 4024 4608  1440 1443 1453 1479 -hsync +vsync 
    Option "Primary" "true" 
    Option "PreferredMode" "3440x1440_44.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "HDMI-1-1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "3440x1440_44.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But this also didn't help much. Honestly speaking I prefer to rely on a script which to check upon booting of the machine whether I am connected to an external display or not and then to switch off the internal display if I am. For the record, I am running `Ubuntu 19.04` and Intel HD4200 and Nvidia GTX 860M.

I also want this switching of the monitors to take place during booting so that the initial login screen and the boot selection screen both to be shown on my external display when it is connected.